# How to include multiple negative lookahead and lookbehind conditions with logical operators in regex

Tags: r

I need to convert all strings with 'dog' appearing in them to 'cat' unless the strings are 'brown dog jumps up' or 'dog barks loudly' in which case they should remain unchanged.

I tried using negative lookahead and lookbehind.

This is my example.

```
str = c("brown dog", "brown dog jumps up", "dog jumps up", "dog barks loudly", "dog ran out")
```

The intended result is:

```
CAT, brown dog jumps up, CAT, dog barks loudly, CAT
```

I tried this for the first condition but it seems to work on an either-or basis, i.e. either not preceded by 'brown' or not followed by 'jumps up'.Does the regex not work in the order of the three conditions (brown/dog/jumps up)?

```
gsub('.*(?<!brown )dog(?! jumps up).*', "CAT", str, perl = TRUE)
```

The following regex works but if I am using an 'OR', why don't "brown dog" and "dog jumps up" remain unchanged?

```
gsub('.*(?<!brown )dog.*|.*dog(?! jumps up).*', "CAT", str, perl = TRUE)
```

Building on the above, I added the third pattern but this changes everything to 'CAT'.

```
gsub('.*(?<!brown )dog.*|.*dog(?! jumps up).*|.*dog(?! barks loudly).*', "CAT", str, perl = TRUE)
```

Why is the `|` functioning as AND in this code? How do I change everything except 'brown dog jumps up' and 'dog barks loudly' to 'CAT'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just check for occurrence of `"dog"` and no occurrence of `strings` and change them to `"CAT"`

```
strings <- c('dog barks loudly', 'brown dog jumps up')
str[grepl('dog', str) & (!str %in% strings)] <- "CAT"

str
#[1] "CAT"  "brown dog jumps up" "CAT"  "dog barks loudly"   "CAT"
```

If you are looking for pattern in `strings` and not for exact match, we could do

```
strings <- paste0(c('dog barks loudly', 'brown dog jumps up'), collapse = "|")
str[grepl('dog', str) & !grepl(strings, str)] <- "CAT"
```

Answer (score 0):

We can do this in single `grep` and using the `invert = TRUE`

```
str[grep("(brown dog jumps up)|(dog barks loudly)", str, invert = TRUE)] <- "CAT"
str
#[1] "CAT"  "brown dog jumps up" "CAT"  "dog barks loudly"   "CAT"
```

Comment: Thanks @akrun but this would change all strings without "dog" into "CAT" as well. I need them to remain unchanged.